# Get more verbose output in React application using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have set up a project using create-react-app. Now I'm working on a different machine and all of a sudden I am getting the error in both `npm run start` and `npm run build`:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

/home/myname/myproject/lib/mylibrary/build/index.js
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Unfortunately this is not enough information for me to debug anything. I am assuming Webpack is doing something funny that is causing the error. How can I get a more verbose error output?

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a completely blank CRA project and you haven't changed anything?

If that is the case and you have nothing to lose I would try creating a new CRA project: `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: It's now recommended that CRA not be installed globally, but `npx` be used instead.